# How should I setup the security of the database for Enterprise Library Logging block

Tags: database, security, logging, enterprise-library

net application running on IIS6. I've setup the logging configurations however it does not log to our database.

I think this should be a permission issue because when I run the app from visual studio it logs fine.

but I"ve already given the app pool identity account datawriter rights to the logging database. The directory security is setup to windows authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Does the account have permission to execute the InsertCategoryLog, AddCategory, and WriteLog stored procs?